# Modbus-tk ModbusInvalidResponseError: Invalid CRC in response

Tags: python, modbus

```
import serial
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

def main():
    master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(serial.Serial(port="COM9",
baudrate=38400, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1))
    master.set_timeout(5.0)
    master.set_verbose(True)
    red = master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 64012, 1)  
    # 这里可以修改需要读取的功能码
    print(red)
if name == "main":
    main()
```

> return:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\WorkSpace\Test\main.py",
> line 20, in main() File "D:\WorkSpace\Test\main.py", line 15, in main
> red = master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 64012, 1) #
> 这里可以修改需要读取的功能码 File
> "D:\WorkSpace\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py", line
> 39, in new raise excpt File
> "D:\WorkSpace\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py", line
> 37, in new ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs) File
> "D:\WorkSpace\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus.py", line
> 356, in execute response_pdu = query.parse_response(response) File
> "D:\WorkSpace\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus_rtu.py",
> line 60, in parse_response raise ModbusInvalidResponseError("Invalid
> CRC in response") modbus_tk.exceptions.ModbusInvalidResponseError:
> Invalid CRC in response

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello djc, `Invalid CRC in response` means you are receiving a response but the checksum is not the right one. That is usually due to noise or wiring issues. You might need to double-check those and maybe debug with something like [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/#:~:text=QModMaster%20is%20a%20free%20Qt,all%20traffic%20on%20the%20bus.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried other tools and it response normally. Using modbus-tk alone is problematic

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and add that info: what tools have you tried and how did you set them up. If you do that I'm sure I would be able to why modbustk is not working.

Comment: I uploaded debugging information and information about other tools

Comment: Nice. I think you are having [this issue](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/112). Some devices are a bit picky with regard to timing. What happens if you remove the `master.set_timeout(5.0)` line to set the default timeout? You might want to try to read several registers instead of just one...

Comment: It was eventually found that what was received was : b'\x01\x03\x00\x02\x1b\\\xee' Convert to decimal : '010300021b5cee' what should have been received is '010300021b5eec3'  one byte is missing.

Comment: If remove the master.set_time(5.0) nothing is received. I try it at least too 0.015. but the received data is still one byte less

Comment: I found a problem that could be caused by my device not having a stop bit .how do i fix it?

Comment: May I ask how do you know there is no stop bit? Start and stop bits are not optional, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1261673/are-the-start-bit-and-the-stop-bits-optional-in-serial-communication).

Comment: I found that the data received was always one less digit, so I modified it modbus_rtu.py line 146：readed_len=0 to readed _len=-1

Comment: Complete data can already be received, but incomplete data reception is still common